# how to change date format and culture?

Tags: c#, asp.net, culture

I need to change the culture of my string to Arabic.

this code :

```
<%# Eval("NewsDate","{0:  dddd   dd / MMMM / yyyy }").ToString() %>
```

will show me these results : Sunday 01 / May / 1994

I tried to show it in Arabic, so it will look like this : الاحد 01 -مايو - 1994

```
<%# Eval("NewsDate","{0:  dddd   dd / MMMM / yyyy }").ToString("{0}:",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar-KW")) %>
```

I added this line to my web.config :

```
<globalization culture="ar-KW" uiCulture="ar-KW"/>
```

but it's not working!

any suggestions please ?

Comment: Have you tried adding culture in `<%@ Page Language="C#" culture="ar-KW">`

Comment: yes I did , and nothing happened !!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to you can change the culture for the current thread so you don't have to do it for each call.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("th-TH", False)
```

Comment: I need it in this form : 

<%# Eval("NewsDate","{0:  dddd   dd / MMMM / yyyy }").ToString("{0}:",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar-KW")) %>

I don't want to handle it from behind code

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it is ok?

```
protected string returnDate(DateTime dt)
{

    System.Globalization.CultureInfo calture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar-KW");
    System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo dtf = calture.DateTimeFormat;
    dtf.Calendar = new System.Globalization.HijriCalendar(); 
    dtf.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    dtf.MonthDayPattern = "MMMM";
    return dt.ToString("dd/MMMM/yy", dtf);
}
```

and

Then call this function in

```
<%# Eval("NewsDate", returnDate(NewsDate) %>
```

Thank you

Comment: I need it in this form : 

<%# Eval("NewsDate","{0:  dddd   dd / MMMM / yyyy }").ToString("{0}:",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar-KW")) %>

I don't want to handle it from behind code

Comment: You can store it to variable and then bind it with Eval.

Comment: sorry , this way will not work .

I tried it and there was an error .

thanks.